# how can I control a application from another application?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an aplication capable of opening a book in audible, selecting a chapter, playing it, pausing. My application should also be able to play music from deezer(or google music) and like/dislike songs/artists based on user input. THe thing is that I need to do this without the user to actually interact with audible or deezer or google play. I want to make a personal assistent and that is what I need those interractions for.

So, long storyshort, how can I control a application from another application?

Comment: That's what API's are for https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=audible&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=audible+developer+api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application you are using does not have an API for it, it's going to be really hard to do. 
But big companies like deezer or google probably have some options for it.